# sum() with pandas return a strange result

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting crazy :S

I performed a sum() with pandas but the result is wrong.

```
csv = pandas.read_csv(file)
tot_p = csv['Amount'].sum()
print(tot_p)
```

and this print out

```
36226.159999999996
```

and the dataset is:

```
[1345.83, 10277.88, 10909.99, 9759.56, 3893.90, 39.00]
```

how is it possible? the sum should be 36226.16

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: floating point precision...

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: This was a topic on a recent python bytes episode.  Floating points don't behave like real numbers.  https://orbifold.xyz/numbers.html